# Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden`. Botframework v4

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

So i created a bot in azure and downloaded it. The free 1000 calls from LUIS reached its limit. I created a subscription in azure portal (I did do the docker container something). Followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription) until step 6. When i click the endpoint url and query directly in the browser it is working fine.

I added it to the bot via Bot Emulator by clicking + sign in services and adding the bot model there. But when i run bot i get the title error. I noticed in the .bot file the authoring key and subscription key added by the bot emulator is the same.

So i changed the subscription key to the one of the keys generated by azure and still the same error. I have tried reseting the authoring key still same and deleting my luis.ai account and created a new one. (still same email because that is the one logged in azure portal.) and still the same.

Here are some pictures for reference and the error.

I also tried testing it in luis.ai and got this result. 
[image]

but when i check it is set to the new resource.
[image]

Here is a pic of the bot file after adding luis via Bot emulator. It has same authoring key and subscription key (still forbidden) 
[image]

so i changed it now with subscription key (still forbidden).
[image]

Here it is working properly when tested directly in the URL.
[image]

For reference:

azure portal
[image]

luis.ai
[image]

and the error
[image]

How i add luis in the bot.
[image]

Here is the code for the bot service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Configuration;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class BotServices
    {
        public BotServices(BotConfiguration botConfiguration)
        {
            foreach (var service in botConfiguration.Services)
            {
                switch (service.Type)
                {
                    case ServiceTypes.Luis:
                        {
                            var luis = (LuisService)service;
                            if (luis == null)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("The LUIS service is not configured correctly in your '.bot' file.");
                            }

                            var endpoint = (luis.Region?.StartsWith("https://") ?? false) ? luis.Region : luis.GetEndpoint();
                            var app = new LuisApplication(luis.AppId, luis.AuthoringKey, endpoint);
                            var recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(app);
                            this.LuisServices.Add(luis.Name, recognizer);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, LuisRecognizer> LuisServices { get; } = new Dictionary<string, LuisRecognizer>();
    }
}
```

I am trying to solve this for 4 days already. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the code where you initialize the `LuisApplication`? You can find [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_cs) here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the question with the botservice of luis application.

Comment: Can you verify something? Remove those luis entries from your bot file. Add a new one, ensuring that you use the endpoint keys beginning with `12ccc` or `b575`. Do not use the authoring key beginning with `ad9c` at all. Do you still get the 403 error?

Comment: @mdrichardson The emulator add those keys automatically. Then i changed them directly in the bot file, is it okay? And yes sir i am still getting the forbidden error when i changed the subscription keys to one of the keys.  Is it relevant that i have not published this bot yet in azure? Because this is new i refactored the codes. But this' bots previous version is published in azure.

Comment: I think its also worth mentioning that i created a new luis.ai account with free starter key and no subscription key and it worked with no problem.

Comment: Pics updated with the changed keys

Comment: I forgot that you're adding the LUIS endpoint via Emulator, which doesn't ask you what key you want to use. If those pics are accurate, you need to update the keys in your `.bot` file. In the LUIS entries, it's using your `authoringKey` (`ad9c...`), when it should be using one of your `endpointKey`s (`12ccc...` or `b575...`). Replace those in your `.bot` file and let me know how it goes.

Comment: :) You edited your comment while I was typing up a comment. Publishing to Azure should only matter if you're using the "production" endpoint in Emulator and not "development". New account would give you a new starter key, so you'd refresh your key use limits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189555/discussion-between-mdrichardson-and-user10860402).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for all of the images. That is a HUGE help! Here's the problem:

By default, your code looks for the `AuthoringKey` in this section (second line):

```
var endpoint = (luis.Region?.StartsWith("https://") ?? false) ? luis.Region : luis.GetEndpoint();
var app = new LuisApplication(luis.AppId, luis.AuthoringKey, endpoint);
var recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(app);
this.LuisServices.Add(luis.Name, recognizer);
```

Since your `.bot` file still has the `authoringKey` set to the one that starts with `ad9c...`, which has hit its limit, your bot keeps running into the 403 error.

So, in your `.bot` file, replace that `authoringKey` with one of your `endpointKey`s (they start with `12ccc...` or `b575...`).

I understand your confusion with this, especially since this requires you putting an `endpointKey` in your `authoringKey` property. I know there's some changes on the horizon to how LUIS bots will use keys, but those are probably a month or more out.

Alternatively, you can change:

```
var app = new LuisApplication(luis.AppId, luis.AuthoringKey, endpoint);
```

to:

```
var app = new LuisApplication(luis.AppId, luis.SubscriptionKey, endpoint);
```

Note: If you make either of these changes, LUIS can *only* query (which is usually fine), since Authoring Keys do everything else (see reference, below)

#### References

These are not so much for you as much as others that might come across this.

[Authoring vs. Endpoint Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-keys)

[Key Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#key-limits)

[Troubleshooting LUIS 403 Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/troubleshooting#my-luis-app-was-working-yesterday-but-today-im-getting-403-errors-i-didnt-change-the-app-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: By the way sir can you check the chat. There is something appearing before every message in the bot emulator.

Comment: Weird my thank you comment is gone. Thank you again sir.

Comment: Responded in chat.

Comment: Sir can you look at this messenger location quick reply question? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55356005/luis-conflict-with-messengers-location-quick-reply